# How to convert float to whole number?

Tags: php, rounding, floor

I have a number stored in mysql as type float.  From what I've read, I should be able to convert a float down by using floor(), but trying this or anything else isn't working.  Hoping someone can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Example..

The database shows price as $25.00 -  In my php page, I have the following code (after converting the price row to $price):

```
$price2 = floor($price);
echo $price;
echo '<br>';
echo $price2;
```

My results are printing:

```
$25.00
0
```

I've also tried replacing 'floor' with 'round'.  Same result.

Comment: What did you expect? You're flooring `'$'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you are using `$25.00` as an input and the `$` makes PHP think that you're trying to round a string -- PHP will round a (non-numeric) string to 0.

- `floor` = round down.
- `ceil` = round up.
- `round` = the same process they taught you in grammar school

But none of those will work if you have a `$` in the string. I suggest that you do something like `'$' . round( str_replace( '$', '', $price ) * 100 ) / 100`. (The multiplication and division makes it so that it is rounded to the nearest penny (instead of dollar), the `str_replace` makes it so that it is dealing with a numeric value, then prepend a `$`. If you're being really fancy, then follow below)

```
$dollar = '$' . round( str_replace( '$', '', $price ) * 100 ) / 100;
// the following makes sure that there are two places to the right of the decimal
$pieces = explode( '.', $dollar );
if( isset($pieces[1]) && strlen( $pieces[1] ) == 1 )
{
    $pieces[1].='0';
    $dollar = implode('.', $pieces);
}
// if you like, you can also make it so that if !pieces[1] add the pennies in
```

Comment: Eh, it would be more correct to say that when coercing a string to a number, the leading `$` will cause the conversion to return 0.  Rounding a string will work just fine, as long as the string can be converted to a number.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the silly mistake. Great explanation! I should have stated that the db shows the value as 25.00 (not $25.00) so I didn't realize the addition of the $ sign in the code above this

Answer (score 0):

As cwallenpoole says, you can't round a non-numeric value.  However, you can make it numeric instead, e.g.

```
$price = '$25.25';
echo sprintf('$%0.2f', floor(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', null, $price)));
```

Comment: Escaping the dot inside of your character class is not necessary. `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.